# az pipelines ERROR: TF400813: The user '' is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

#### pipelines.yml

```
  - script: |
      az login --allow-no-subscriptions -u xx -p xx
      az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/xx project=xx
      az devops user list
    displayName: 'Login Azure DevOps Extension'
```

- resulst

> ERROR: TF400813: The user 'xxx' is not authorized to access this resource.

- But run the command on your own computer, Ubuntu 20

```
az login --allow-no-subscriptions -u xx -p xx
 az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/xx project=xx
az devops user list
```

> Return is normal

#### help me?